# UIPickerView doesn't update

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

I am dynamically loading label values for *UIPIcker* view from a URL under *iOS 5.1.1*, so I need to update it after the view is presented. If I initialize it with values (via the `delegate` method) when the picker is instantiated, everything works find. If I late call `reloadAllComponents` on the picker, it indeed queries the *datasource* via the `delegate` method and retrieving the selected row shows that it really is populated with the new values. The problem is that the fields still display as `blank`. The picker *datasource*, `delegate`, and `IBOutlet` are all set to File's Owner (I'm using a `.xib`). If I load initial dummy values into the picker at instantiation, those values are displayed even after the picker is actually updated. I'm scratching my head about this one. Can anyone explain why the *GUI* values don't update?
Thanks,
Cliff

**[Update]**
Now, I see that if I background the app after the picker has been updated, it redisplays with the correct values]. It really feels like I'm missing a connection. I've tried calling `setNeedsDisplay` with no success.

Comment: do you have any code? Something definitely's wrong. It'd be easier to help you if we can see what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

I had left code out because I had so much application code that I was unwilling to share. I actually figured out the problem. I was populating the picker via an `NSNotification` callback. This apparently doesn't run in the main thread and caused the problem. By ensuring that the body of the notification callback runs in the main thread via

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    MY CODE HERE
});
```

everything now works correctly.
Cliff

Comment: this also fixes a problem when trying to change the frame of the picker in 5.1 via a NSNotification callback, thanks!